# React Navigation - Nested Navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm developing a mobile app using React Native and I have a little dilemma. I have 2 requirements:

1: To be able to navigate back.
2: To have a drawer (slide-in menu)

I'm using React Navigation, which works great for either of the two requirements, but not together (at least as I've understood it).

I have tried using DrawerNavigator, and it allows for a really nice drawer. But I've not been able to create a goback-functionality. In the app you're supposed to be able to open the drawer and navigate. And while you are on a page, and navigate to another, you have to be able to navigate back to the page you came from. And as I've understood it, this is only possible in StackNavigator. But in StackNavigator, there's no drawer-functionality.

So, I'm wondering what are my options?

Nested navigators? I've tried, but ended up with a goback-functionality that only navigated between the navigators, not the pages in the StackNavigator. So I'm not sure if what I want is possible with nested navigators.

Another possibility would be to create a completely custom Drawer-component which I toggle by state in parent component.

Do you have any tips on this issue?

The code I've tried for nested navigator:

```
const Nav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Single: Single,
  Tag: Tagsview,
  Privacy: Personvern,
  Search: Search,
  Contact: Contact,
  About: About,
  Login: Login,
  MostPopular: MostPopular,
  MostShared: MostShared,
  TagsSingle: TagsSingle,
  Newest: NewestImages,
}, {
  contentComponent: ({ navigation }) => (
    <NavMenu navigation={navigation} />
  ),
},
{
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#2D2D2D',
});

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({     
  Login: Login,
  Drawer: {screen: Nav}
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#2D2D2D',
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Put some code to better understand your issue, because that should completely work

Comment: In my opinion if an app has a slide-in menu it should not be possible to "navigate" back by sliding. Instead there should be a back button/arrow in the top left corner.  It think that also conforms with android/ios design guidelines. So my first try would be to convince the customer to drop that feature. Using the same gesture for two things can be relatively confusing and counter-intuitive for a user.

Comment: @st4rl00rd I added the code setting up the stack/DrawerNavigator. So it should be possible to navigate through the pages in DrawerNavigator with the backbutton-functionality from StackNavigator?

Comment: @trixn Yeah, I totally agree. What I want is the backbutton from stackNavigator.

Comment: Just tried your code, works just fine, see https://www.videosprout.com/video?id=32d0eb71-e58b-49d1-baab-a78d861ed1c6; What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @st4rl00rd Hm. But if you navigate further, like three pages in, and then try to navigate back, would you be able to use the backbutton for each page? And open drawer on all pages? I’ve used the latest version

Comment: I'm using 2.4.1, and I'm able to navigate as further as I want, even been able to use three parent top children on top of the stack, it just uses parent state to manage the whole navigator in a centralized way through the navigation prop, because that's the way it's supposed to work, can you upload your project somewhere to help you debug that?

Comment: @st4rl00rd Okay, then I will test it out some more. Will do that if I can’t figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the code I had worked, as pointed out by @st4rl00rd, but it needed a little tweak.

So, if you want to have both a slide-in menu, and a goBack-functionality you have to use stackNavigator with a nested drawerNavigator and it works great.

This is the code after editing:

```
const Nav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,    
}, {
  contentComponent: ({ navigation }) => (
    <NavMenu navigation={navigation} />
  ),
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#2D2D2D',
});

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Single: Single,
  Tag: Tagsview,
  Privacy: Personvern,
  Search: Search,
  Contact: Contact,
  About: About,
  MostPopular: MostPopular,
  MostShared: MostShared,
  Newest: NewestImages,
  TagsSingle: TagsSingle,
  Drawer: {screen: Nav}
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#2D2D2D',
});
```

Basically what I needed to do, was to swap the pages. Put all the pages but the HomeScreen in 'rootStack', because these are the ones to you can navigate backwards to in the stack. And leave the Home-screen in the drawerNavigator, so that when you navigate to 'Drawer' in stackNavigator, you can use the openDrawer-function.